# How to calculate the hash value of a torrent using Java

Tags: java, hash, bittorrent

How can I calculate the hash value of a torrent file using Java? Can I calculate it using [bencode](http://code.google.com/p/bee-encode/)?

Answer (score 6):

Torrent files are hashed using [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). You can use [`MessageDigest`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) to get a SHA-1 instance. You need to read until `4:info` is reached and then gather the bytes for the digest until remaining length minus one.

**Note**: This implementation works for most torrents, but the .torrent file is not guaranteed to end with the info key.

```
File file = new File("/file.torrent");
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (!builder.toString().endsWith("4:info")) {
        builder.append((char) input.read()); // It's ASCII anyway.
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (int data; (data = input.read()) > -1; output.write(data));
    sha1.update(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.size() - 1);
} finally {
    if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}

byte[] hash = sha1.digest(); // Here's your hash. Do your thing with it.
```

Comment: i tried bytes to convert to hash value but the hash value is different ...
      for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(Integer.toString((hash[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
      }

Comment: @Ramesh - perhaps the file got mangled when you saved it?  Did you (perchance) use a `Reader` or `Scanner` to do that?  Anyway, you haven't supplied enough information to allow someone else to figure out what is really going on.

Comment: @Ramesh: you're right, the hash should exist of only the `info` key of the torrent's dictionary. This is located at end of torrent file, bordered by `4:info` and `e`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: ya it works fine now so i can also get the seeds ..Leechers and file size like this????

Comment: There is no guarantee that the info-dict is at the very end of the torrent file. Mostly it is, but there are cases when the assumtion that it ends at "remaining length minus one" is false. For example if the root-dict of the torrent file contains a "signatures"-key (http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0035.html)

Comment: The above code take such a dirty shortcut by not bdecode and find the exact end of the info dict, that I would classify it as faulty. See explanation why [**here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670592/create-torrent-hash-info/19008851#19008851) A proper method how to calculate a infohash can be found [**here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749085/calculating-the-info-hash-of-a-torrent-file/19800109#19800109)

Comment: why `output.size() -1` ? It`s length

Comment: @Hett: It's answered in 1st paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[BitTorrent Specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html)

This should have everything you need, from a more official resource

Comment: As a complement to the official specification linked by Nicholas I would also recommend the inofficial specification wiki found at: https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

Answer (score 1):

> Can I calculate it using bencode?

No. That is for encoding bittorrent metadata, not actual files.

Comment: I've no idea.  But that's a completely different question to the one you asked here.  Why don't you focus on this one first ... and provide more information as requested above.