# info_hash calculated for torrent incorrect

Tags: java, urlencode, bittorrent, sha

OK I've searched all related questions, and source code where available, just stuck.
I'm using this code from a related question:
[How to calculate the hash value of a torrent using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436823/how-to-calculate-the-hash-value-of-a-torrent-using-java)

to build the SHA-1 hash.

Then I'm doing this to encode it, to be included in the tracker request:

> URLCodec c = new org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec();
>   return new String(c.encode(info_hash));

But the tracker replies with no peers.  By tracing uTorrent, I can see the correct hash for my  torrent file is:
T%7f%bc%a6%92%bb%8a%8b%2aL%b9%a3%0f%a59%f3%98%e6%0c%eb

But my code outputs:
%E4%AF%3C%96%9E%D2%BAJt%C0%C3%B4%12%93%D4h%3B%9A%2CF

Any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: Basically you need to urlencode *binary* form of infohash. This is frequently asked question, actually SO already has answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072234/bittorrent-tracker-request-format-of-info-hash

Answer (score 2):

```
private string encodeInfoHash(string code) 
{
      //string code = "78820B24672757A60BEF15252E93F3D0C4DEB5C3";
      byte[] codeB = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(code);
      string info_hash_encoded = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i += 2)
      {
            string tmpCode = code[i].ToString() + code[i + 1].ToString();
            int j = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCode, 16);
            char s1 = (char)j;
            bool isSpecChar = false;
            if (s1.ToString() == "." || s1.ToString() == "-" || s1.ToString() == "~")
                  isSpecChar = true;
            if ((Char.IsLetter(s1) || Char.IsNumber(s1) || isSpecChar) && !Char.IsControl(s1) && j <= 127)
            {
                  info_hash_encoded += s1.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                  info_hash_encoded += "%" + tmpCode.ToLower();
            }
      }
      return info_hash_encoded;
}
```

I use C# , you can read my blog for more detail
http://hello.xiaoyezi.xyz/urlencode-the-info_hash.html

Comment: New User Answer Review: thanks for taking the time to contribute answers. If you like a tipp, I would recommend to start an answer with a text and then show code. You did nothing wrong, it just looks like a "code only" answer, which is frowned upon. Same is true for giving links without summarizing the content.